# Formatting mysqli output table with different functionalities

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am outputting newsletter email registrations.
How can I format them into tables and what edits can I do so that I can drop that row also.

My PHP code is :

```
<?php include "navbar-datacheck.php" ?>
<?php 
    include "../backend/db.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * from newsletter";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);  
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            print "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Email ID: " . $row["email"]."<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select Specific Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500910/mysql-select-specific-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct your table comprising of all the *newsletter* details in the following manner,

```
// your code 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
// your code
```

> ... what edits can I do so that I can drop that row also.

As you can see, I have added a third column *Action* in your table so that you could delete a row of your choice at any given time. So once the user clicks on *Delete* link, this is how you should process and delete the corresponding record in **delete.php** file.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // Now delete the corresponding record from the table 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, One more thing can I create a button which would copy the whole email ID's so that I can send them mails using cc.

Comment: @Bhanusingh Actually you don't have to create any additional button there, simply fetch the row details, **including email**, from your table, send a mail and then delete the record.

Comment: @Bhanusingh You should get into the habit of *accepting* answers, it will not only *close* the questions(if solved) but it will also encourage other developers to answer your queries. Right now all your questions are floating around SO as *open* questions. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: <?php include "../backend/db.php" ?>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
 $sql="DELETE FROM newsletter WHERE id = '$id'";
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
    header("location:newsletter");
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $mysqli->error;
}
} 
?>  Problem Deleting

Comment: Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow. Will remember next time onwards.

Comment: @Bhanusingh what does `$mysqli->error` show? Also, do `echo $sql;` and make sure the `DELETE` query is correct.

Comment: I have database with name newsletter having id and email. According to that I guess there is no error here. No error. Its just blank page.

Comment: @Bhanusingh A *blank page* means something is broken, add these two lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your PHP scripts and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: Nothing. Again blank.

Comment: @Bhanusingh Did you place these error reporting lines in *delete.php* page or some other page?

Comment: @Bhanusingh There's definitely you're doing something wrong in *delete.php* page. Paste the entire code on [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @Bhanusingh Few things to debug from here, 1. Make sure your URL is correct i.e. `<domain>/delete.php?id=<someIdValue>` 2. Make sure your database connection is okay 2. If everything fails, then remove all code from *delete.php* page, and do `var_dump($_GET);` and first see what you're getting there. Followed by this, incrementally construct your code.