# Is it necessary to loop through a MySQL query result even if just one row?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

After a particular query using PHP, I have a  `$result` variable with only 1 row of data returned by the database.

I want to retrieve the data from this single row, but am not too keen on needing an entire while loop to do this seemingly simple request.

Is there a better way to get the data? I think `mysqli_fetch_row()` might do the trick, but it seems to only allow access via integer indexes.

Any better solutions??

Comment: Duplicate: [PHP - Simple way to read single record from MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811153/php-simple-way-to-read-single-record-from-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that there will always be only one row, then no, you MUST not use a loop.

Also, you can use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of `mysqli_fetch_row()`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a loop. For single results it's not necessary, but you're not going to get into any trouble for using it.

Comment: AFAIK, a loop increases time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

if you know you only want 1 row, you don't need a loop, just assign the variables as you would inside a loop.  Also use "limit 1" in the query.

Comment: Right, but I'm already sure that the results will be limited to 1 row, as it is based on a WHERE clause that calls on a row with unique ids