# query multiple rows in mysql as variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - Simple way to read single record from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811153/php-simple-way-to-read-single-record-from-mysql)

I want to query multiple rows in mysql as variable. for example:

```
SELECT name, tid FROM term_data WHERE vid = 2
```

this is the result:

```
name | tid
-----|----
Jack | 55
Tony | 87
John | 32
```

then I want to use while:

```
while (...) {

print "My name is: $name and my ID is: $tid";
//name and tid should be printed from database. 

}
```

I can query one row and put it in a `while` but How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: What language are you outputting from?

Comment: Which extension are you using to access MySQL?  [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?  [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)?  Perhaps show the code that you have so far.

Comment: Your intention is not clear. Show the source table also.

Comment: you should look into http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @shyam: There's a big red box at the top of that page advising people not to use [ext/mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).  Why are you advising people to do otherwise?

Comment: @Jake What will be the desired result of your query? Do you want to return just a single row?

Comment: Thanks Everyone eggyal's answer works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#example-1716):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//Conection
...
$query= "SELECT name, tid FROM term_data WHERE vid = 2";

if (query_run=mysql_query($query)) {
while ($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
$name=$query_row['name'];
$tid=$query_row['tid'];

echo 'My name is'.$name.'and my ID is'.$tid;
}
}
else {
echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Only thing remains is resolving the connection which is up to you.

Comment: As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*