# How to get single record by search query and skip other records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

To get a record I normally use this kind of query:

```
select * from tablename where columnName = 'abc'
```

This query search for all `abc` in the table. However I want just to get only first record that has `abc` and don't look for other.

Please suggest me sql query for this purpose.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why you don't use  `limit 1` or `top 1` in your query?

Comment: You could have googled this. This is a faq let alone a duplicate. Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling my SO comments re googing many versions/phrasings of your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Simple way to read single record from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811153/php-simple-way-to-read-single-record-from-mysql)

Comment: What you think that I have not tried. I tried to google it.. But could not find any good ans. Therefore it might look silly ques to you but its imp for me.

Answer (score 2):

This will just return the first instance as it scans the table.

select * from tablename where columnName = 'abc' limit 1;